# How to use datepicker package

Tags: flutter, monthcalendar

there are not much documentation on how to use the date picker package in flutter, for some reason however the calender is not showing up, is there a way to be able to make a date range picker?

main.dart

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: []);
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
          platform: TargetPlatform.iOS,
      ),
      home: HomeScreen(),
      localizationsDelegates: [
      GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
      MonthYearPickerLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

```
child: IconButton(
  icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_month),
  onPressed: () {
    SfDateRangePicker(
      view: DateRangePickerView.year,
      selectionMode: DateRangePickerSelectionMode.range,
    );
  },
),
```

Comment: is the SfDateRangePicker not working? Perhaps you can also try some other datepicker package if you are not finding success like https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_date_pickers or https://pub.dev/packages/calendar_date_picker2

Answer (score 0):

You can use package [date_time_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/date_time_picker):

Now you can put this container widget in your widget tree to get the result something like below
[image]

```
Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Color(0xff8E8E8E),
                    ),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                  ),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: DateTimePicker(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                            ),
                            dateMask: 'dd/MM/yyyy',
                            initialValue: DateTime.now().toString(),
                            type: DateTimePickerType.date,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                              fontSize:16,
                              fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                              color: Color(0xff362477),
                            ),
                            firstDate: DateTime(1800),
                            lastDate: DateTime(2050),
                            // This will add one year from current date
                            validator: (value) {
                              return null;
                            },
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              if (value.isNotEmpty) {
                                setState(() {
                                  // _selectedDate = value;
                                });
                              }
                            },
                            onSaved: (value) {
                              if (value!.isNotEmpty) {
                                // _selectedDate = value;
                              }
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding:
                                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 150),
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.calendar_today_outlined,
                              color: Colors.grey,
                              size: 20,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```